# Format variable length strings into columns in python

Tags: python, formatting, guizero

How can you format variable length strings into uniform columns in python? I'm reading data from a database into columns (2 columns total) and I am trying to left-align the first column and right-align the second using python `format()`.
Here is the code I am currently using:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")

for items in cur:
    list_box.insert(1, "{:1<50}{2:>58}".format( 
        items[0], str(items[1])))
```

Here is the current result:

[image]

No matter what values I try in `format()` the dates will not right-align uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use a Monospaced font (each characters occupy the same amount of horizontal space)? Than it should work like this:

```
datas = [
    ('********', '2021-07-28 20:5:0'),
    ('*****', '2021-07-28 20:57:1'),
    ('************', '2021-07-28 20:57:10'),
    ('*****************', '2021-07-28 20:57:33'),
    ('**   ******', '2021-07-28 20:57:34'),
    ('********', '2021-07-28 20:57:59'),
]

for data, datum in datas:
    print(f'{data: <80}|{datum: >20}')
```